# ClearCase find and exec with %CLEARCASE_PN% in cmd always returns same element

Tags: windows, clearcase, command-prompt, cleartool

I executed the following command in cleartool.exe:

```
    cleartool> !
    Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
    ...
    X:\dyn_view\vob\path>cleartool find . -type l -exec "cleartool describe
%CLEARCASE_PN%" -print
```

But the element output is always the same regarding *exec*, albeit being different in *print*. How to output the correct list in the *exec* part of the command?

Example output:

```
symbolic link ".\path\fileA.txt" -> ../../path/fileA.txt
  created ...
.\anypath\fileB.txt
symbolic link ".\path\fileA.txt" -> ../../path/fileA.txt
  created ...
.\anypath\fileC.txt
```

Where fileA is always the same (part of exec parameter), only fileB, fileC, etc., change (part of print parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the example listed in "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)"

```
X:\dyn_view\vob\path>
cleartool find . -type l -exec "cleartool describe \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

So:

- no `-print` at the end
- '`\"`' around `%CLEARCASE_PN%` to take into account spaces in the path

Note that you can combine that with [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) for a refined display:

cleartool find . -type l -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%n %[slink_text]Tp\n\"
\"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""

> Example:

```
Y:\VOB_A>
cleartool find . -type l -exec "cleartool describe -fmt "%n%[slink_text]Tp\n\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
.\Directory\createsymlink.txt -->..\..\VOB_B\SymlinkFolder\createsymlink.txt
```

With:

```
%[slink_text]Tp
```

representing "Target of symbolic link, after link is traversed."